# Multiplying dense matrices with small values

Tags: performance, optimization, matrix

If multiplying two matrices, `A*B = C`, either of them can have large number of values which is negligible, ie near zero.  There isn't really any block structure to zeroes.

What solutions do I have to reduce operations?
I thought of primarily trying to permute matrices to get into block-zero structure but that may by itself be `O(3)` cost.  CRS or CCS doesn't seem to have many ready-to-use dgemm equivalents.

Comment: If the amount of negligible values is enough to make the matrices considered 'sparse', then I would suggest using an algorithm for sparse matrix multiplication with an added paramater to detect when a value can be considered negligible. Try this and regular matrix multiplication to see if there is any performace increases as it should be trivial to do this as algorithms and library support for this is common.

Comment: @xshoppyx sparse matrix-matrix is fairly uncommon.

Comment: I misread your post. I apologize. :)